# Presented view controller covers status bar in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, statusbar, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a presented view controller in iOS 7 that doesn't have a navigation bar, but the status bar is visible. I tried setting the edgesForExtendedLayout to UIRectEdgeNone, but that doesn't seem to do anything (unless I show a navigation bar, which I don't need).

Doesn't seem to be a topLayoutGuide in interface builder (view uses a nib, not a storyboard) and was having trouble with that anyway.

Could hide status bar like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

But I don't really want to hide it. Note there are some similar questions, but they discuss using a navigation bar. This one, I don't want the navigation bar.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OW9F.png

EDIT:
Switched to using a storyboard and was able to get the top layout guide working properly

Comment: If you uses a UISearchDisplayController you can do this to add the searchbar to the navigationbarcontroller. Code:  `UISearchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;`

Comment: Not presenting with a navigation controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to using a storyboard and was able to get the top layout guide working properly